# Read http Headers for extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, http-headers, firefox-addon

I want to get the complete information of a http header when a http request has made by using  http-on-modify-request.

Example of the information i want to get:

[image]

i have this code:

```
myObserver.prototype = {
 observe: function(subject, topic, data) {

  if("http-on-modify-request"){
    var httpChannel =        
  subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        alert("URI: " + httpChannel.originalURI.spec);
        alert("User-Agent: " + httpChannel.getRequestHeader('user-agent'));
  }

},
 register: function() {
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                      .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
 },
unregister: function() {
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
 }
}
```

Comment: you can use ajax's getAllResponseHeaders()

Comment: I don't want the response headers only the request headers before the request actually leave

Comment: my bad.. the real answer is that you can't, AFAIK. see http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: Dude yes it can be done.I've searched for it.I just need an small example

Comment: kudos, just trying to help. i'll be anxiously awaiting a workable solution...

Comment: and btw, if this is for an extension, you should probably should have mentioned that in the question; i just assumed you were a noob who stumbled across some completely N/A code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used a way of getting them all at once, but you should be able to get them individually with the way you are doing.

I tried it too for the referer, but it didn't work, but i found that if you do:

```
 httpChannel.referrer.host
```

(referrer has two r's), it shows the address of the referer.

Additionally, you might want to take a look at the source code of [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/), it does what you are trying to do.

You might find additional help in this link: [nsITraceableChannel, Intercept HTTP Traffic | Software is hard](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/)

And this one: [Howto: XHR Listening by a Firefox Addon](http://www.ashita.org/howto-xhr-listening-by-a-firefox-addon/)

Answer (score 0):

My Two cents.

**IN JAVASCRIPT**

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eSQ2X/)

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
console.log(headers);
alert(headers)
```

**IN PHP**

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; ?>
```

Comment: I don't want for the javascript only Iam working on an extension which means only through observers you can catch the http headers.

Comment: can you explain me what are you doing precisely?

Comment: I the code above you can see that i get the header for the user-agent before the http request leave.Now i want to do the same with other headers like referer etc.But it can't be done with the same way like the user agent(i don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

Your observe function should look like this:

```
observe: function(subject, topic, data) {

  if (topic === "http-on-modify-request") {

    var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
    alert("URI: " + channel.URI.asciiSpec);

    channel.visitRequestHeaders(function(name, value) {

      // do something with each header
      if (name === 'User-Agent')  {

        alert(name+': '+value);
      }
    });
  }
},
```